# Using HTML 5 form to limit the amount of numbers in the input box

Tags: html

I want my input box to only allow 4 numbers (not characters).

I have tried a few different solutions on stackoverflow but none of them seem to work for me.

You can limit the amount entered by characters but not by numbers.

So far i have tried:

```
maxlength="4" pattern=".{4}"
```

and

```
maxlength="4" pattern="([0-9]|[0-9]|[0-9]|[0-9])"
```

which none of those work for me.

Anyone any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Try :   <input type="number" name="quantity" min="0" max="9999">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `input type = "number"` and give the min and max value as following:

```
<input type="number" name="quantity" min="0" max="9999">
```

[HTML-5 Input Type Number](http://www.w3schools.com/htmL/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_number)

Comment: Thanks, i have changed the min to "1800" and max to "2015" as i want the user to input a year between then, this seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

its working for me just re-checked on fiddle.

```
<input type="text" id="83filename" maxlength="2" />
```